# iteratively consume command argument element by element

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists

I would like to iteratively "consume" elements from a list and use these in Tikz. A \foreach with parallel lists does not work for this case. I also don't need indexing capabilities since I use each element only once. In other words, the iteration can be destructive.

Here is a MVE that illustrates the idea. Instead of the 'X' in the node I would like to have the elements, one by one, passed as #1. The separator used in the list is not critical.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,fit,backgrounds}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{m} {
  \foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,3} {%
      \node at (\x,\y) {X};%  <- elements here instead of X
}}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \test{a,b,c,d,e,f}
   %or: \test{a/b/c/d/e/f}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,fit,backgrounds}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listofitems}


\NewDocumentCommand\test{m} {
  \readlist\myarray{#1}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,3} {%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\z}{3*(\x-1)+\y-ifthenelse(\x<3,\x,\x+1)+1}
      \node at (\x,\y) {\myarray[\z]};%  <- elements here instead of X

}}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \test{a,b,c,d,e,f}
   %or: \test{a/b/c/d/e/f}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pointer to `listofitems`and `readlist` was helpful. My code is more complicated than the minimal example above, and I therefore combined it with a counter and `\itemtomacro` to be able to access the list item easily. The code works along these lines:

```
\usepackage{listofitems}    

\NewDocumentCommand\test{m} {
  \readlist\valarray{#1}%
  \global\newcount\mycount\mycount 0\relax%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {%
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,#1} {%
    \global\advance\mycount 1\relax
    \itemtomacro\valarray[\the\mycount]\val

    ... do something with \val ...

}}}
```